# phpMyAdmin error 1064

Tags: phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1064

I have an error with creating a database for taking customers variables. How do I correct the problem?

[image]

Comment: if you have a mysql problem, post the query here. also this is probably not related to phpmyadmin.

Comment: Don't post picture unless you are force. Add a [MCVE]

Answer (score 0):

The dialog box seems to be covering over the useful info.  What parameters do you have for `Gender`?

I think `ENUM` needs strings, not numbers.